# Custom form field type and user-defined function for it

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

This is my first question here, but I hope I will get a lot of help :)
So, here's the issue I've faced a few days back.

For a project I need a custom form field, which will allow the user to select a numeric range.

Example:

```
Number: greater-than 3 and lower-or-equal-than 5
```

I've managed to create my custom form field type just fine. I've made a custom method into my repository which appends the where clause part and whole thing worked.

Recently I needed the very same component on several other places into my project. Now, I hate duplication, so I decided that the logic which modifies the DQL has to reside on a central location. According the features given in Doctrine, this has to be the UDF (user-defined function).

I went ahead and tried to implement the UDF, to no avail.

I've managed to learn and use the Parser and the Lexer components of the Doctrine ORM package, but it seems to me like this is not enough.

To explain in depth, here is the resulting query:

```
SELECT something FROM SomeBundle:Something something
WHERE in_range(someProperty, gt, 3, lte, 5)
```

It has to be transformed to:

```
SELECT sometable.* FROM sometable sometable
WHERE someProperty > 3 AND someProperty <= 5
```

I'm fine parsing it, but Doctrine2 requires a condition operator after the UDF, so the syntax should be something like this:

```
SELECT sometable.* FROM sometable sometable
WHERE in_range(someProperty, gt, 3, lte, 5) = 1
```

Using this syntax, one still need to assign values for all the parameters (eg: gt and lte), which will also need a separate function which will track which parameters have been assigned already and which were not. In addition, this solution does not seem to work, as the parser seem to have issues parsing my function arguments :D

All I need is simple query modifier.

If possible, I would like to achieve better syntax as well. Something like this would be acceptable:

```
someProperty is in_range(gt, 3, lte, 5)
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance to all participants!

*P.S According the Doctrine2 site, the UDFs are meant to be used for "implementing vendor specific functions". Perhaps I'm not looking at the right solution for my issue. Any suggestions?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing my own Expr class.

Some advantages include:

- you are not bound to use specific parameters, so you can pass yourself whatever you need
- you can craft your query the way you need, because its the __toString() method that returns the query to be used

A thing to note here is that currently Doctrine2 does not support custom Expr classes, so in order to use mine, I had to use the __toString() method and check if the result is not empty, before passing it to the andx()/orx() methods of the query builder.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use BETWEEN (http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples)?

Comment: The user need to be able to specify the comparison condition, while between() forces greater-or-equal and lower-or-equal. This will be my fallback, if I did not succeed in any other way.